# How to overwrite z-index for one of the select2.js element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have 4 elements (element 1 is in fixed header and elements 2,3,4 in my form) of which i have applied **select2 (customisable select box with support for searching)**. but elements 2,3,4 are overlapping the element 1, i need to set **z-index** only for the element 1, if i change it in **select2.js**, it is applied for all the elements, so the element 1 should be on top of elements 2,3,4

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the z-index directly in `select2.js` specify a class with a better [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

```
.nav-bar .select-box {
   z-index: 
}
```

*where `nav-bar` has to be replaced with the id or classname of the navigation bar that you have specified and `select-box` is the class specified for that select box.